# Replace не выполняется

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

Есть код:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write("qwerty / asdfgh / zxcvbn")
f = f.replace('/', '\n')
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
f = f.read()
print(f)
```

Почему метод replace не работает? выдает ошибку:

> 'int' object has no attribute 'replace.

Comment: replace не будет работать с "указателем" на файл. Поменяйте до записи `f.write("qwerty / asdfgh / zxcvbn".replace('/', '\n'))`

Comment: код в вопросе не может ошибку приведённую вызвать. Вы должны получить: `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) относится к строками, а не файловым объектам:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    text = "qwerty / asdfgh / zxcvbn"
    text = text.replace('/', '\n')
    f.write(text)  # 'qwerty \n asdfgh \n zxcvbn'

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()  # 'qwerty \n asdfgh \n zxcvbn'
    print(repr(text))  
    print(text)
```

Comment: если метод replace не работает с указателем на файл. Тогда почему возвращается как раз таки указатель на файл из функции открытия документа?
(Учу по книге Доусона, и из за этого такая ошибка и вылилась.

`def open file(file name. mode):
    the_file = open(file_name. mode. encoding='utf-8')
    return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line`

Comment: А там тоже строка, т.к. `.readline()` возвращает строку

Comment: что ерунда ?def open file(file name. mode): the_file = open(file_name. mode. encoding='utf-8') return the_file def next_line(the_file): line = the_file.readline() line = line.replace("/", "\n") return line?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????